# Extracting the text after the initial substrings between square brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I would like to extract the substring from the string, such as

Case 1:

```py
text = "some_txt" # → some_txt
```

Case2:

```py
text = "[info1]some_txt" #  → some_txt
```

Case3:

```py
text = "[info1][info2] some_text" # → some_txt
```

Case4:

```py
text = "[info1][info2] some_text_with_[___]_abc" # → some_text_with_[___]_abc
```

What I did was

```py
match = re.search("^\[.+\] (.*)", text)
   if match:
   result = match.group(1)
```

It works okay except case 4, which gives `abc` only. I want to get `some_text_with_[___]_abc` instead.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want `r"^(?:\[[^][]+])+\s*(.*)"`, right? Or, just `re.sub(r'^(?:\[[^][]+])+\s*', '', text)`. Note it is not a good idea to use builtins as variable names. Please clarify what your requirements are since "I am stuck with python regular expression" is not quite helpful.

Comment: Yeah. It works. Thanks alot for the help. But it is quite hard for me to understand. is it possible  to explain this regex pattern?

Comment: Please confirm my edits are fine.

Comment: Your edits are very good. Thanks a lot. I should have done it myself. :D

Comment: what I really want is this:  r"^(?:\[[^][]+]\s*)*\s*(.*)"

Comment: That is, if there can be whitespace between substrings in brackets.

Comment: Note it is not a good idea to quantify groups having a single obligatory and all other optional patterns, that leads to performance issues and catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Did my answer help finally?

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, you can use

```py
r"^(?:\[[^][]+](?:\s*\[[^][]+])*)?\s*(.*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bUYfEp/1/).

If you are not actually interested in whether there is a match or not, you may use `re.sub` to remove these bracketed substrings from the start of the string using

```
re.sub(r'^\[[^][]+](?:\s*\[[^][]+])*\s*', '', text)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bUYfEp/2).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\[[^][]+](?:\s*\[[^][]+])*)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\[[^][]+]` - a `[`, then any one or more chars other than `[` and `]` as many as possible and then a `]`
  - `(?:\s*\[[^][]+])*` - zero or more occurrences of zero or more whitespaces and then a `[`, then any one or more chars other than `[` and `]` as many as possible and then a `]`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.